# How to store an edittext value in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist, android-edittext

I am new to Android. Now I am developing a project. My project has 2 edittext, 1 button, and a custom listview. When I click the ADD button, I want to display my edittext data in a custom listview.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
EditText edt1,edt2;
ListView itemsListView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add_id);
    edt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.credit_id);
    edt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.gpa_id);
    itemsListView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_items);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new 
CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, generateItemsList());
            itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            edt1.setText("");
            edt2.setText("");
        }
    });
}
private ArrayList<Item> generateItemsList() {

    String itemName=edt1.getText().toString();
    String itemDescription=edt2.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<Item> list= new ArrayList<>();
    Item item=new Item(itemName,itemDescription);
    item.getItemName();
    item.getItemDescription();
    list.add(item);
    return list;
}
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_row_items, 
parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Item currentItem = (Item) getItem(position);
    viewHolder.itemName.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
    viewHolder.itemDescription.setText(currentItem.getItemDescription());
    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemDescription;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        itemName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item_name);
        itemDescription =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item_description);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the correct way? @Arbaz.in

Comment: Is `Item` a custom object that you created?

Comment: @Shihab007 post `Item`  model class

Comment: @Shihab007  remove the for loop.

Comment: @Shihab007 your looping concept is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected your method , please check

```
private ArrayList<Item> generateItemsList(){
    String itemName=edt1.getText().toString();
    String itemDescription=edt2.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<Item> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    Item item=new Item();
    item.setName(itemName);
    item.setDescription(itemDescription);
    list.add(item);

    return list;
}
```

this method will return the current item name and item description in a list.

Declare a global `arraylist` to save multiple entries Like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    EditText edt1, edt2;
    ListView itemsListView;
    ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_id);
        edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credit_id);
        edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gpa_id);
        itemsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_items);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String itemName = edt1.getText().toString();
                String itemDescription = edt2.getText().toString();

                Item item = new Item(itemName, itemDescription);
                item.getItemName();
                item.getItemDescription();
                list.add(item);
                CustomListAdapter adapter = new
                        CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                edt1.setText("");
                edt2.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. actually i want to display my data in custom listview.Your method not work in listview. @Quick learner

Comment: can u tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: Data is not add listview. Just update data same place..exp: 1st i input 5 and 6 click ADD button display 5,6 in below listview...2nd i input 10,30 it is not add listview..just 5 replaces 10 and 6 replaced 30.. @Quick learner

Comment: check my answer now